# Filter and use text out of a txt file

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I want to filter it so that it only uses the latest information for each different combination of PART and FUNCTION so that I only end up having around a handful of results per combo instead of thousands of outdated ones. 
ID is based on time here.

This is what I've currently got:

```
    while((line = br.readLine())!= null){ 
        info = line.split(",");

        Map<String,String> qgi=new HashMap<String,String>();

        qgi.put("ID",info[0]);
        qgi.put("FUNCTION",info[1]);
        qgi.put("PART",info[2]);
        qgi.put("STATE",info[3]);
        sourceList.add(qgi);
    }

    for (int i = 0, len = sourceList.size(); i < len; i++) {
        Map<String,String> gqi =(Map) sourceList.get(i);

        if ( gqi.get("PART").equals("chw") && gqi.get("FUNCTION").equals("diskusage") && gqi.get("ID").equals("20181122125601"))//Get highest value with those parameters
        { 
            resultList.add(gqi);
        }
    }
```

So currently my ID equals a specific date and time, and I want it to be the highest ID for that specific combination(chw and diskusage).

I want to essentially do something like

```
if(a.get("b").equals("something") && a.get("c").equals("something") && thisCombinationsID >= everyOtherIDWithThisCombination{
    resultList.add(a);
}
```

Comment: Doing like in your question, you will have 4 values in your map, which basically represents just a single data set, consisting of a single *ID*, a single *FUNCTION*, a single *PART* and a single *STATE*. Is that what you want to have? You cannot filter it properly because it only has 4 totally different values... See the answer by @JBNizet and create one object per data set. Those are filterable from a `Map` or `List`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class `RowKey`, with a `part` and a `function`, and proper `equals` and `hashCode` overrides (the IDE can generate that for you).

Create a class `Row`, with a `rowKey` (of type `RowKey`), an `id` and a `state`.

Create a `Map<RowKey, Row>`containing, for each row key, the row that has the max ID (empty initially).

Iterate throught the lines of the file. For each line, create an instance of Row.

Then check if an entry already exists in the map for this row key. If not, or if the new row has a bigger ID than the existing row, store the new row in the map. The `Map.merge` can help doing that.

At the end, the values of the map contains what you want.

The implementation is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: "Create a class RowKey, with a part and an info, and proper equals and hashCode overrides (the IDE can generate that for you)." I'm assuming you mean a 'part' and a 'function' right, or what would you have me do with info(which is a C-style array in my piece of code)?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

```
final class Data {

    private int id;
    private final String function;
    private final String part;
    private final String state;

    public Data(String id, String function, String part, String state) {
        this.id = Integer.parseInt(id);
        this.function = function;
        this.part = part;
        this.state = state;
    }
}

List<Data> sourceList = new ArrayList<>();

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] info = line.split(",");
    sourceList.add(new Data(info[0], info[1], info[2], info[3]));
}

final Predicate<Data> specificCombination = data -> "something".equals(data.function) && "something".equals(data.part);
final Comparator<Data> compareByIdDesc = (d1, d2) -> Integer.compare(d2.id, d1.id);
Data data = sourceList.stream().filter(specificCombination).min(compareByIdDesc).orElse(null);
```